# Similar ADCs, Different Applications? (ADS122C04 vs ADS1220)

Tags: adc, load-cell

I'm looking at two different ADCs from TI, the [ADS122C04](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads122c04.pdf?ts=1701360083610) and the [ADS1220](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1220.pdf?ts=1701367536686&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS1220). The first page overviews are nearly identical - other than the communication protocol, the **only** difference is that the 1220 has a low-side switch and the 122C04 does not. However, the Applications sections are completely different. I am about to do a deep dive into both datasheets to see if I can uncover more differences and figure out why they are recommended for different applications, but I don't want to waste too much time if it turns out the Applications section is arbitrary or something. Is there a short explanation as to why very such similar chips would have such different usages?

Bonus question: the reason I am looking at these chips is because I want to use them to collect data from load cells as a replacement for [this HX711 breakout module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13879). The 1220 is recommended for Resistive Bridge Sensor Measurements, but the 122C04 is not. However it seems close enough to the HX711 - sufficient PGA, correct input configuration, resolution and supply voltage match, etc. Is there a reason why I couldn't use the ADS122C04 for this application? We already use that chip so I would prefer to stick with it instead of adding the 1220 to our development needs.

Comment: Excepted the only difference of the low-side switch (SPI and I2C), I have not seen different applications for the two circuits. ADS122C04 seems a very "little" better (noise).